# In MVC, why does my controller need to receive a "new { id = restaurant.Id }", as opposed to "restaurant.Id"? Are the not both simply int's?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

So my mvc controller method here take an int id as an argument. Im wondering why new "{ id = restaurant.Id}" is required and "restaurant.Id" is not sufficient.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Restaurant restaurant)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Update(restaurant);

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = restaurant.Id });
        }
        return View(restaurant);
    }
```

Comment: What is the result if you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because MVC expects an object from which to retrieve the values to bind to the action parameters. In other words, you could do:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", restaurant);
```

Mvc will crawl your object for properties that match the name and type of your action's arguments and should therefore bind to the restaurant's 'Id' property.
If you just pass the restaurant's Id, though, MVC will crawl the type of whatever you restaurant's id property is.

Hope this helps. If it does, please mark it as the answer ;)